# Making sure two different wordpress website has auto login

Tags: login

I have been working on two different installations:
https://pax-security.nl
https://pax-security.nl/intranet and want to make sure that if you login on the domain it will also auto login on the intranet website on the same domain.

1. I made sure both websites are installed on the same database.
2. Made sure the salt keys are the same on both configs.
3. The code I entered on the main domain config file:

---

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'pax-security.nl' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH',    '/' );
define( 'COOKIEHASH',    md5( 'pax-security.nl' ) );

define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE',      'wp_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta' );
```

4. The code I entered in the intranet config file:

---

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'pax-security.nl' ); // Dot prefix
define( 'COOKIEPATH',    '/' );
define( 'COOKIEHASH',    md5( 'pax-security.nl' ) );

define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE',      'wp_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta' );
```

I can create an account on the first install and use it on the intranet website, but it is not automatically logging in.
What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both sites `COOKIE_DOMAIN` define has missing a `.` in front of domain name. It should read:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.pax-security.nl' );
```